# How does this program to calculate Armstrong numbers between two intervals work step by step?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, intervals

```
class Armstrong {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int low = 999, high = 99999;

    for(int number = low + 1; number < high; ++number) {
      int digits = 0;
      int result = 0;
      int originalNumber = number;

      // number of digits calculation
      while (originalNumber != 0) {
        originalNumber /= 10;
        ++digits;
      }

      originalNumber = number;

      // result contains sum of nth power of its digits
      while (originalNumber != 0) {
        int remainder = originalNumber % 10;
        result += Math.pow(remainder, digits);
        originalNumber /= 10;
      }

      if (result == number)
        System.out.print(number + " ");
      }
  }
```

How does this program work? It would be very helpful. Program to find Armstrong between two intervals? Can someone explain step by step? Help me out.

Answer (score 1):

#### Steb-by-step Explanantion

Initialize the start and end of the interval with 999 and 9999
You can change these numbers but ensure that `low` is always lesser than `high`:

```
int low = 999;
int high = 99999;

for (int number = low + 1; // Create a variable number and assign it one number greater than low
    number < high;         // This loop should keep repeating until number is less than high(end of the interval)
    ++number               // After each repetition, increment the value of number by 1
    ) {
```

Create a variable `digits` to store the number of digits in number.
For example, if number is 100, this will be later set as 3 as the algorithm proceeds:

```
  int digits = 0;
```

Create a variable `result` that will store the sum of powers of numbers:

```
  int result = 0;
```

Copy the value of `number` to a local variable `originalNumber` because it has to be modified:

```
  int originalNumber = number;
```

The logic of calculating number of digits in a number is keep dividing it by 10 until the number is 0.
Every time you divide any number by 10, the last digit is stripped out. So every time the last digit is stripped out, increment digit by 1 (`digit++`)

```
  // number of digits calculation
  while (originalNumber != 0) // Continue this while loop till originalNumber is not 0
  {
    originalNumber /= 10;     // Divide the number by 10. Dividing a number by 10 removes its last digit.
    ++digits;                // One digit was removed in the above step, which means it has to be counted, so increment digit by 1
  }
  // For example, for originalNumber = 423,
  // 423 / 10 = 42 : digits = 1 (first loop)
  // 42 / 10 = 4 : digits = 2   (second loop)
  // 4 / 10 = 0 : digits = 3    (third loop)
  // Now originalNumber has become 0, so the while loop condition originalNumber != 0 will be false and the loop will stop.
  // Now we have digits = 3, which is the number of digits in 423

  // When program reaches here, digits will have the number of digits in the
  // number "originalNumber"
```

Copy `number` again to `originalNumber` because we want to modify the number
again and `originalNumber` has become 0 because of the digit counting loop above:

```
  originalNumber = number;
```

An Armstrong number is a number which is equal to the sum of digits to the power of its number of digits.

*e.g.: in 153, `(1^3) + (5^3) + (3^3) = 153`. We are obtaining the cube of each digit(1, 5, 3) because 153 has 3 digits 1, 5, 3.
If it was say 50, we would check `( 5^2 + 0^2)` because 50 has 2 digits (50 is not Armstrong, because `25 + 0 = 25` which is not equal to 50)*

We saw above dividing a number by 10 removes the last digit (423 / 10 = 42)
Similarly, if we only want this last digit, we can get it by modulus 10 (`% 10`): (`423 % 10 = 3`) (`42 % 10 = 2`) (`4 % 10 = 4`)

```
  // Let's assume originalNumber is 153
  while (originalNumber != 0) // Same as above, keep looping till the originalNumber is not 0(i.e. all digits have been removed)
  {
```

Extract the last digit to `remainder`, (for 153: `153 % 10 = 3`) (for 15: `15 % 10 = 5`)

```
    int remainder = originalNumber % 10;
```

Now we have the last digit, we need to raise this digit to the number of
digits i.e. 3(for 153): `(3^3) = 27`. We do this using `Math.pow(3, 3)`. Add this number to `result`. In the end after each loop's number's power is added, at the end of the `loop`, `result` will contain their sum:

```
    result += Math.pow(remainder, digits);
    originalNumber /= 10; // Remove the last digit (same as above, for 153: 153 / 10 = 15)
    // After this line finishes, one rightmost digit will be removed, this will keep
    // happening till originalNumber = 153 becomes 15, then 1, then 0.
    // When originalNumber is 0, loop stops and we will have the total sum in result
  }
```

For an Armstrong number like 153, `result` will also contain 153. For a non-Armstrong number it will contain something else.

```
  if (result == number) // For 153, both will be equal.
    System.out.print(number + " "); // This will only execute if result is equal to number, or in other words, only if the number is Armstrong
}
```

#### Improvements

As per single responsibility principle, each function or class must exactly do one thing. You have a monolithic `main()` method that:

- Defines the interval
- Counts the digit of each number in the interval
- Calculate the sum of powers of digits
- Check if number is Armstrong and print it.

I would prefer breaking down each operation to a separate method, so that it improves readability and maintainability while respecting single-responsibiliy principle:

```
class Armstrong {

   public static int countDigits(int number) {
      int digits = 0;
      while (number != 0) {
        number /= 10;
        ++digits;
      }
      return digits;
   }

  public static int digitPowerSum(int number, int power) {
    int result = 0;
    while (number != 0) {
      int remainder = number % 10;
      result += Math.pow(remainder, power);
      number /= 10;
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static boolean isArmstrong(int number) {
    int digits = countDigits(number);
    int sum = digitPowerSum(number, digits);
    return sum == number ; // will return true if both numbers are equal else false
  }

  public static ArrayList<Integer> armstrongNumbersBetween(int low, int high) {
      ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
      for(int number = low + 1; number < high; number++) {
        if (isArmstrong(number)) {
          numbers.add(number);
        }
      }
      return numbers;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int low = 999, high = 99999;

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = armstrongNumbersBetween(low, high);

    for(int number : numbers) {
      System.out.print(number + " ");
    }

  }
}
```

Here, each method does exactly one thing and this helps in better reusability. You just have to call the required methods to perform a specific operation.
If something is unclear, let me know.